# Non-holomorphic L-functions

Tags: reference-request, l-functions

In some old notes, I found the following conjecture:

Let $\mathbb T$ denote the unit circle and let $\chi:{\mathbb N} \to {\mathbb T}$ be fully multiplicative. Then the L-series
$$
L(\chi,s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s},
$$
defined for ${\rm Re}(s)>1$, cannot be extended to a holomorphic function on $\{ {\rm Re}(s)\ge 0\}$.

Who formulated this conjecture? What related results are known?

Comment: What does "fully multiplicative" mean? completely multiplicative? 

Comment: The second question is easy: it is false. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15176/analytic-continuation-of-dirichlet-series-with-completely-multiplicative-coeffici/20888#20888. The answer to the first question is "We'll never know". Indeed, how are you going to *prove* that some lost manuscript of Archimedes (or some private letter of Euler, or...) did not contain the full discussion already?